# Audit Failure event when IWbemServices::Release()

Tags: events, wmi, release, audit

I have this WMI client's code. It connects well and works correctly. But...

```
const wchar_t server[] = L"MyServer";
const wchar_t login[] = L"User";
const wchar_t password[] = L"Password";
const wchar_t domain[] = L"";

HRESULT hr = NULL;

// COM
hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. "
        << "Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hr << endl;
    return;
}

// Security
SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_W authIdentity;
SecureZeroMemory(&authIdentity, sizeof(authIdentity));
authIdentity.User = (USHORT*)login;
authIdentity.UserLength = wcslen(login);
authIdentity.Password = (USHORT*)password;
authIdentity.PasswordLength = wcslen(password);
authIdentity.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_INFO authninfo[1];
SecureZeroMemory(authninfo, sizeof(SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_INFO));

// NTLM Settings
authninfo[0].dwAuthnSvc = RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT;
authninfo[0].dwAuthzSvc = RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE;
authninfo[0].pAuthInfo = &authIdentity;

SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_LIST authentlist;
authentlist.cAuthInfo = sizeof(authninfo) / sizeof(SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_INFO);
authentlist.aAuthInfo = authninfo;

hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL,
    -1,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
    &authentlist,
    EOAC_NONE, 
    NULL);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hr << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
}

// Locator
IWbemLocator *locator = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WbemLocator,
    0,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&locator);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. "
        << "Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hr << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
}

// Service
std::wstring networkResource = L"\\\\" + std::wstring(server) + L"\\root\\cimv2";
IWbemServices* service;
hr = locator->ConnectServer(
    _bstr_t(networkResource.c_str()),
    _bstr_t(login),
    _bstr_t(password),
    _bstr_t(L"MS_409"),
    WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT,
    _bstr_t(domain),
    NULL,
    &service);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hr << endl;
    locator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
}

hr = CoSetProxyBlanket(
    service, 
    RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,
    RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,
    COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
    reinterpret_cast<RPC_AUTH_IDENTITY_HANDLE>(&authIdentity),
    EOAC_NONE
    );

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hr << endl;
    service->Release();
    locator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
}


// Do something...
```

The problem occurs on disconnect: on service->Release() call the 2 Audit Failure events occur in the Security event log on target machine. It looks like an attempt to login but using the local account, not remote.

```
service->Release();
locator->Release();

CoUninitialize();
```

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=680&EvtSrc=Security&LCID=1033) is the description of error (0xC0000064)

How to solve this and what's the reason? I've spent a lot of time but have no idea...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer through the comments on MSDN:
[Comments of CoSetProxyBlanket function description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692692(v=vs.85).aspx#CommunityComments)

And here is the complete description:
[Setting Security on a Remote IUnknown Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393608(v=vs.85).aspx#_HMM_SETTING_SECURITY_ON_A_REMOTE_IUNKNOWN_INTERFACE)

You have to create IUnknown interface from you IWbemServices instance and set security to it:

```
IUnknown* pUnk = NULL;
service->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void**) &pUnk);

hr = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pUnk, 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, 
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, 
        COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL, 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, 
        reinterpret_cast<RPC_AUTH_IDENTITY_HANDLE>(&authIdentity),
        EOAC_NONE
        );

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout << "Count not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hr << endl;
    pUnk->Release();
    service->Release();
    locator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
}

// Now you can do what you want...
```