# (WMI) IWbemServices::Release() throws "Access Denied" exception when connected to remote machine

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi

In C++, I can't find a way to appropriately terminate a WMI session with a remote server.  Any attempt to release the `IWbemServices` pointer throws an exception; the TCP connection to the server remains established until the process exits (it's open after the last `CoUninitialize` call).  This problem (thrown exception) does not occur when connecting to the local machine.

I've looked at a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719313/audit-failure-event-when-iwbemservicesrelease), but the solution from Microsoft (retrieving the `IUnknown` pointer and releasing it first) didn't solve the issue.

Here's the code (error checking has been omitted for readability):

```
HRESULT hRes = S_OK;

IWbemLocator* pWbemLocator = NULL;
IWbemServices* pWbemServices = NULL;

// these three pointers are already initialized...
PWCHAR wcUser; // L"theuser"
PWCHAR wcPass; // L"thepassword"
PWCHAR wcAuth; // L"ntlmdomain:THEDOMAIN"

std::wstring wstrNsPath = L"\\\\remoteserver\\ROOT\\CIMV2";

hRes = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

hRes = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pWbemLocator);

// this returns S_OK :)
hRes = pWbemLocator->ConnectServer((BSTR)wstrNsPath.c_str(),
        (BSTR)wcUser,
        (BSTR)wcPass,
        NULL,
        WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT,
        (BSTR)wcAuth,
        NULL,
        &pWbemServices);

hRes = CoSetProxyBlanket(pWbemServices,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,
        COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
        NULL, // domain info already specified in 'wcAuth'
        EOAC_NONE);

// do some queries..

// cleanup
pWbemServices->Release(); // on remote sessions, this throws an exception
pWbemLocator->Release();
CoUninitialize();
```

The exception is displayed in the debug output (Visual Studio):

```
onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\call.cxx(1234)\combase.dll!0000ABCDEFABCDEF: (caller: 0000FEDCBAFEDCBA) ReturnHr(1) tid(4321) 80070005 Access is denied.
```

Is this expected behavior? Should the connection between the client and server not be terminated once the session is released?

I attempted to follow MSDN's [advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/setting-authentication-using-c-?redirectedfrom=MSDN#setting-security-on-a-remote-iunknown-interface) and added the following after the `CoSetProxyBlanket()` call in the code above.  It didn't change anything.

```
IUnknown* pUnknown = NULL;
pWbemServices->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (LPVOID*)&pUnknown);
if (pUnknown)
{
    hRes = CoSetProxyBlanket(pUnknown,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,
        COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
        NULL,
        EOAC_NONE);
    pUnknown->Release();
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT** So after capturing session packets, it would appear that setting the proxy security with `pAuthInfo == NULL` causes the request to be made by the current logged on user of the client machine.  It ignores the credentials that I provided when calling `ConnectServer`.  I'm aware that the `COAUTHIDENTITY` structure allows you to pass the correct credentials to `CoSetProxyBlanket`, but I'd like to avoid having to input the domain as a separate variable.  In other words, is there a way that this information can be extracted using the `wcAuth` when the request is made to a remote server? If so, how could I distinguish local vs. remote requests?

Here is the output from Wireshark that led me to believe this is the problem (see packet 1617):

```
No.     Time        Source      Destination Protocol Length Info
1615    162.221354  [CLIENT_IP] [SERVER_IP] DCERPC  174 Alter_context: call_id: 8, Fragment: Single, 1 context items: IRemUnknown2 V0.0 (32bit NDR), NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
1616    162.228517  [SERVER_IP] [CLIENT_IP] DCERPC  366 Alter_context_resp: call_id: 8, Fragment: Single, max_xmit: 5840 max_recv: 5840, 1 results: Acceptance, NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE
1617    162.229396  [CLIENT_IP] [SERVER_IP] DCERPC  612 AUTH3: call_id: 8, Fragment: Single, NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: .\[client_user]
1618    162.229495  [CLIENT_IP] [SERVER_IP] IRemUnknown2    182 RemRelease request Cnt=1 Refs=5-0
1619    162.235567  [SERVER_IP] [CLIENT_IP] TCP  60 49669 → 59905 [ACK] Seq=1606 Ack=4339 Win=64768 Len=0
1620    162.235567  [SERVER_IP] [CLIENT_IP] DCERPC  86  Fault: call_id: 8, Fragment: Single, Ctx: 0, status: nca_s_fault_access_denied
```

Comment: Is this a first chance (internally caught) or second chance exception?

Comment: @SimonMourier it's first-chance

Comment: There are tons of first chance (C++) exceptions that occur when you use Windows libraries. That's how Microsoft handles errors internally more and more (it used to be fully transparent years ago because they didn't use C++ exception, just error code checks).  As long as it's handled, I wouldn't care.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Getting WMI Data from a Remote Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-a-remote-computer)

And you could refer to the Doc: [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-on-a-remote-computer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.  If you are not using the current logged-on user token, you must specify the `pAuthInfo` parameter of `CoSetProxyBlanket` to a valid `COAUTHIDENITY` structure pointer.  The docs for `IWbemLocator::ConnectServer` actually state that it's best practice to include the domain in the `strUser` parameter... and that if you do so, you must pass the authority string as `NULL`.

One thing to note is that if `ConnectServer` succeeds, you don't have to go crazy with the sanitizing of the username string for correctness; the login either worked or it didn't (and breaks/throws an exception, depending on how you handle errors).  In other words, just search the string for the domain delimiters (`'\\'` or `'@'`) and split them appropriately into domain name and username.